# Updating data in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm working on a project on CodeIgniter, but I got an issue right now, I tried to resolve it, but this got the problem.

Here we are : In my code below, I can't update whatever I wan't on my database, but I can insert whatever in.

I'm supposed to update 'mode' from 'landing news soir' to 'landing Offre Gratuite' on the row depending on customer_id.

EDIT : Yeah sry I should've precised that I tried something like               if(1===1)  but still can't update data.

```
    elseif($all === "gratuite") 
        {    
            $mode1="landing news soir";
            $mode2="landing Offre Gratuite";

            $this->db->select('mode');
            $this->db->where('customer', $customer_id);
            $this->db->where('mode', $mode1);
            $query= $this->db->get('newsletters_inscriptions');


            $update_data = array(
                    'mode' => $mode2);

            if($query->row()){

                $this->db->where('customer', $customer_id);
                $this->db->update('newsletters_inscriptions', $update_data);
            }

            else{

                $insert_data = array(
                'newsletter' => '2',
                'customer' => $customer_id,
                'liste' => 175,
                'mode' => 'landing Offre Gratuite');

                $this->db->insert('newsletters_inscriptions', $insert_data);
                $newsletter_inscription_id = $this->db->insert_id();

                // Mise en base dans la liste des objectifs - Stats logs tracking
                $this->stats->enregistrer_objectif(null, $this->inscription_newsletter, $customer_id, $newsletter_inscription_id);
            }
        }
```

I tried a lot o' ways to resolve it but still can't make it. Thank you.

Comment: u just need to check this first `print_r($query->row())` what r u getting

Comment: one more suggestion use `if(count(($query->result_array())>0)` instead of `if($query->row()){`

Comment: or use `if (isset($query->row()))`

Comment: Mhh I'm on the controller right there, can I put print_r or var_dump on the view ? I think so

Comment: just try `if(isset($query->row())){`

Comment: Yeah i should've precised that i tried something like (1===1) on my if but still can't update data

Comment: ok, use `print_r($query->row())` before this line `if($query->row()){` and share the result

Comment: sadly I can't because there is a redirection and other queries after..

Comment: `print_r($query->row()); exit;` use exit